# Javascript, jquery error TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked around at questions similar to the above and none of them have helped.

Here are my scripts

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="network.json"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>      
        <link href="ajs_network1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="ajs_network1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
```

Here is the function trying to call JQuery

```
$(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: optArray
    });
});
```

For some reason its bringing up the error

```
TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function.
```

I am guessing ive done something wrong with the scripts ?

Comment: You need to add jQuery UI library `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Load jquery at the top of the head tag

Comment: Agreed with Satpal autocomplete is a jQueryUI's plugin so include this library after jQuery lib.

Comment: add this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Satpal  ReferenceError: $ is not defined. I get this error ?

Comment: @JqueryKing  $ is not defined. I get this error ?

Comment: Well i guess you have included your external .js file before you included jqueryui library

Comment: sorry about this haha there were hidden characters in between some of the letters in the link making the link unable to be found. All sorted. thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links were correct i was using. But because i was retrieving links online i didnt put in http at the beginning. So the links would now be :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>‌​
```

Also, there were hidden characters for some reason when i copied the link over so the link wasnt working. When working with this make sure your browser is retrieving the links. FireBug help me with this. Click 'net' and it will tell you what scripts the browser is importing.

Thankyou to all that helped :)

Answer (score 6):

> by just adding this link reference my issue was resolved

```
<script async src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding those links into your code as you are missing those

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```